# python, using columns without header and index

Tags: python, excel, header, date-format

I have a table like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIUfU.png)

I want only date column and units column (column 1 and 5), but with date in another format.
I used code like this:

```
`import pandas as pd

customer_calls = pd.read_excel("sales.xlsx", usecols=[0, 4])



customer_calls["OrderDate"] = pd.to_datetime(customer_calls["OrderDate"]).dt.strftime("%Y%m%d" + "00")
customer_calls.to_excel("sales_YYYYMMDD.xlsx")

print(customer_calls)`
```

It gives me what I wanted:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z81oO.png)

I need it without header and index. But when I use header=0 or header=None, then can not read line:

```
`customer_calls["OrderDate"] = pd.to_datetime(customer_calls["OrderDate"]).dt.strftime("%Y%m%d" + "00")`
```

cause there is no "Orderdate" name of column anymore. I tried to use 0 instead of name and all kind of stuff, but it always says error. How can I remove header and index but still choose date column after that?

I've read dozens of examples here, nothing solved this. Or I can no see it.

Comment: pandas data requires a header for each column.

Comment: than what to use?

Comment: if you want data with no header, then create a list or lists. since lists have no headers.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the headers and index, then essentially you are seeking only the `values`. If so, you extract the values and use the `tolist()` method.

Here is an example of this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# extract values only
data = df.values.tolist()

print(data)
```

Here is the result of the above:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The values are now just a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it! Posting it for the future similar questions. It can be done really easily in panda, just two more lines.

```
import pandas as pd


# Read the file and specify which column is the date
customer_calls = pd.read_excel("sales.xlsx", usecols=[0, 1])


# Output with dates converted to YYYY-MM-DD
customer_calls["OrderDate"] = pd.to_datetime(customer_calls["OrderDate"]).dt.strftime("%Y%m%d" + "00")
customer_calls.to_excel("sales_YYYYMMDD.xlsx")


#set the location of the first row with columns
customer_calls.columns = customer_calls.iloc[0] 
#remove first row from the dataframe rows
customer_calls = customer_calls[1:]
#display
print(customer_calls)
```

it gives output like this:

```
0   2020010600     East
1   2020020900  Central
2   2020031500     West
3   2020040100     East
4   2020050500  Central
5   2020060800     East
6   2020071200     East
7   2020081500     East
8   2020090100  Central
9   2020100500  Central
10  2020110800     East
11  2020121200  Central
```

changed data format and without header